# Python call method on integer object

Tags: python

I just want to understand the behavior of method call on integer object.

I can't call `__add__` method directly on integer.

```
5.__add__(5)
```

This gives me: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

However, doing `num = 5` and call `num.__add__(5)` works fine.

How assigning name to an integer object makes difference?

Comment: This is because the `5.` may be confused with a float number by the parser. Use `(5).__add__(5)` instead, or `5 .__add__(5)`.

Comment: Because then num=5  becomes an instance of class Integer and python calls the magic method `__add__` of integer class. Otherwise python doesn't know if it is 5 or 5.0

Comment: No, N Randhawa, 5 is already a member of that class: try running `dir()` on it to see.

Answer (score 3):

it is just syntax. The Parser reads:

- `"5."` -> a float :)
- `"__add__"` -> why that? I don't understand :(